# The function which changes Tabulation on other symbol doesn't work

Tags: c, function, struct

I am doing the function which opens a file, gets a symbols and if there are tabulation (sign '\t') - it changes on other sign (in my function on "^I").
I read a lot of forums, checked a lot of sites and recommendations/ I tried to use ChatGPT and all answers are similar. But I didn't find controversies with my interptretation (see below). When I compile the file with this function I don't have any mistakes. But when I use the function, it doesn't change Tabulation... this function just sends chars in stdout as is in file....

```
void output_opt5_file(char *name_file) {
FILE *f = fopen(name_file, "r");

if (f != NULL) {
    int symbol = fgetc(f); //char symbol = fgetc(f); - тоже не сработало
    while (symbol != EOF) {            
        if (symbol == '\t')
        {
            printf("^I");
        }
        else putc(symbol, stdout);
        symbol = fgetc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

}

I can't find my mistake. I used char, integer for variable "symbol" (commented text), but I can't get the right result.
Example of usage:
I sent file test.txt:

> ```
> before this text  one tab       before this text two tab
> ```

I am waiting:

> ^Ibefore this text  one tab^I^Ibefore this text two tab

I got:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I cut stdoup. Becuase above I used simple:

```
 printf("^I");
```

For checking the simplest possibility to out: ^I
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66WtQ.png

Comment: Please show a short example of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: And there are actual tab characters in the file? If you look at the file in a hex-editor, does it contain any `09` bytes (the ASCII code for `'\t'`, assuming ASCII or UTF-8)?

Comment: I've tried the code: can't see any problem.

Comment: And was the function changed  tabulation? Without any problem... I put sign of Tabulation in txt-file uses button "Tab".

Comment: My text editor is set to "use spaces instead of tab". But I made a file that I know contains a `\t` and checked with a hex-dump tool. Input `"ab\tcd"` output `"ab^Icd"`.

Comment: My brain is explosing! I use Visual Studio Code and my OS: Linux Ubuntu. I used button "Tab" and now I've tried four spaces... Nothing!

Comment: aaaaaa! Nothing! May be try to differ text-editor, nano or vim?!

Comment: Make a test file programmatically. Just print a string such as `puts("ab\tcd");` and redirect the output to the test file.

Comment: Check around in your VSCode settings, I'll bet there is a setting about tabs and spaces which isn't what you expect (using spaces instead of tabs is *very* common in code-oriented editors). A different editor *might* work, unless it's also have this setting.

Comment: Guys! thanks a lot! The Recipe with stdin-stdout helped me find problem! But the advice from @Someprogrammerdude to point me the main problem. All is working. I did new text-file in nano and ...yeap! Bingo!